# How can I pay a fine I was charged with in Italy while I am now in Budapest?

Tags: italy, milan, fines

I am a student in Budapest. I was in Italy in Milano, and I bought a ticket in the underground to go to Sesto to catch my bus to Venice. Unfortunately, I bought a wrong ticket as I did not know that Sesto was outside Milano. The conductor at Sesto checked my ticket and gave me a fine. I explained to him that I am not Italian and I do not know that Sesto is outside Milano, and he still insisted that I pay. I did not have enough money. So, he gave me a check with fine and told me that I can pay when I come back to Budapest in the Posta. Yesterday, I went to the Posta in Budapest to pay. But, unfortunately, they did not accept and told me I cannot pay at the Posta. can anyone advise on how I can pay the fine?

Comment: Did the conductor write down your name, address etc?

Comment: Unless he got your real address, I would honestly leave it. I already have one French and two German train fines - the simple fact is they're not going to waste resources to track you down and convince the authorities where you live to have you prosecuted.

Comment: As soon as the conductor got the OP's national ID number or taxcode, then the company is able to hire a debt collecting agency to reclaim the amount, since Budapest is in EU and debt collection agreements are now active and mutual among all countries. The bus company may still, upon their discretion, decide not to proceed with collection if their fees are excessive.

Answer (score 6):

First, if you gave them your actual address, they might mail you regarding this, but they might as well give up on the fine. The payment process at the "posta" refers to Italian post offices only. Should you plan another trip to Italy soon, you might solve it then.

Finally, if you want to be over-correct and get this solved, you can [contact their "Customer Support"](https://www.atm.it/it/AtmRisponde/INostriContatti/Pagine/Risarcimentiecontravvenzioni.aspx) regarding ticketing fines. I would not count on them being able or willing to correspond in any language other than Italian.

> **Direzione Sosta e Parcheggi e Supporto Clienti**
>   *Ufficio Supporto Clienti* *
>    V.le Stelvio, 2 – 20159 Milano
>   Apertura al pubblico: dal lunedì al venerdì dalle 9.00 alle 12.30 e dalle 13.30 alle 16.00
>   Telefono: 02.48.03.83.45/46
>   Fax: 02.48.03.82.70
>   E-mail info.multe-sanzioni@atm.it